# Computing scalar product and string manipulation in C

Tags: c, parsing, split, string-formatting

For my homework I need to do a program that:

1. Get 2 strings (in `char` format, max 100 characters) from `scanf`, (like:{1,2,3, 4} and {0,1, 2,0})
2. Take the numbers between spaces (I'm using `strtok` right now)
3. Convert them to `double` (I'm using `strtod` for that)
4. Do the scalar product

Before copy my actual code, I want to ask you guys, if you know how to learn this type of manipulation easily; my exam is going to be like that, take string do thing, parse them convert them, but I'm having a lot of difficulty to learn how. And the man, and my book are to simplified, and I can't understand.

Thanks to all, I hope you can help me before I definitely mad about that.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  //TODO TAKE ARGOMENTS
  //TODO EXTRACT THE NUMBERS
  //TODO CONVERT THEM TO DOUBLE
  //TODO DO THE SCALAR PRODUCT

  //prototypes:

  unsigned manipulate_string(char vet[100]);

  //functions:

  unsigned manipulate_string(char vet[100]){
      const char s[4] = " ,{}";
      double vfinal[100];
      char *token;
      char *stringPtr;
      char *todPtr

      //get the first token

     token = strtok(vet, s);

     //walk through other tokens
     while( token != NULL ) {
         printf( " %s\n", token );

         token = strtok(NULL, s);

         double d = strtod(vet, &stringPtr);
         vfinale[100]=d

         return d;
     }
}

 int main () {
     char vet1[100];
     char vet2[100];
     double vet1f[100];
     double vet2f[100];
     const char s[4] = " ,{}";
     char *token;
     printf("inseert first vector\n");
     scanf("%[^\n\r]", vet1);
     printf("insert second vector\n");
     scanf("%[^\n\r]", vet2);

     vet1f[100]=manipulate_stringvet1[100]);
     vet2f[100]=manipulate_string(vet2[100]);

     printf("the first one is\n",vet1f);
     printf("the second one is\n",vet2f);


}
```

Now the code is only about see the string manipulated, after, don't think I would have problem to do a function that do the scalar product.

Thanks another time, for help and time wasted on it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of problem in your code:

- some variables are miss-spelled: `vfinal` // `vfinale`
- some semicolons are missing: `char *todPtr`
- some parentheses is missing: `vet1f[100]=manipulate_stringvet1[100]);`

But, even if these little problems are corrected, you need to understand array manipulation:

- `double vfinal[100];` declares an array of 100 `double`
- `vfinale[100] = d;` set the value of the **101th** element of the array to `d`: you try to write outside the array.

You have the same problem (4 times) in these lines:

```
vet1f[100]=manipulate_string(vet1[100]);
vet2f[100]=manipulate_string(vet2[100]);
```

And you have another problem: the function `manipulate_string` does not what you want: you make it to return only one `unsigned char` while what you want would be to modify the `vet1f` (or `vet2f`) array (which should have been passed as a parameter)

---

If we take this piece of code :

```
 token = strtok(vet, s);

 while( token != NULL ) {
     token = strtok(NULL, s);
     double d = strtod(vet, &stringPtr);
     vfinale[100]=d

     return d;
 }
```

We can see two problems:

- First the `return d;` is inside the loop, making to exit before last token has been read
- In the loop block (between the `{}`) you read a new token befor using the previous, thus:

  - The fist token is lost
  - When `token` will be `NULL`, it will be passed to `strtod` and it's not what you want.

---

Most compiler can have their warning enabled, try with `-Wall` (GCC, clang, icc...) or /W4 (visual studio)

Comment: Yes, chances are that the OP are actually trying to *return* an array of `float`, loosing also any information about the actual number of elements read, by the way.

Comment: I have fixed the problems, and now the strtok part work, only thing that remain is do the strtod part.. but it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Even if i fixed the problems, there is just a thing that i can't understand: Why the strtod is not converting my string.. Here is the code fixed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//TODO TAKE ARGOMENTS
//TODO EXTRACT THE NUMBERS
//TODO CONVERT THEM TO DOUBLE
//TODO DO THE SCALAR PRODUCT


//prototipi

unsigned manipulate_string(char vet1[], char vet2[]);
//funzioni

unsigned manipulate_string(char vet1[], char vet2[]){
  const char s[4] = " ,{}";
  double vfinale1[100];
  double vfinale2[100];
  char *token1;
  char *token2;
  char *stringPtr1;
  char *stringPtr2;
  int c1=0, c2=0;

//get the first token

token1 = strtok(vet1, s);

//walk through other tokens
while( token1 != NULL ) {
   printf( " %s\n", token1);

   token1 = strtok(NULL, s);

}


token2 = strtok(vet2, s);

while( token2 != NULL ) {
   printf( "%s\n", token2);

   token2 = strtok(NULL, s);
}

 double d = strtod(vet1, &stringPtr1);
 vfinale1[c1]=d;

 double u = strtod(vet2, &stringPtr2);
 vfinale1[c2]=u;

 return *vfinale2;
 return *vfinale1;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
   char vet1[100];
   char vet2[100];
   double vfinale2[100];
   double vfinale1[100];

   printf("insert first vector\n");
   scanf("%[^\n\r]", vet1);
   printf("insert second vector\n");
   scanf(" %[^\n\r]", vet2);

   manipulate_string(vet1, vet2);


   printf("the first one is %.2f\n", *vfinale1);

   printf("the second one is %.2f\n", *vfinale2);

}
```

output:

```
insert first vector
1,2,3,4
insert second vector
5,6,7,8
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 the first one is 0.00
 the second one is 0.00
```